# Approximating $\log(1+\exp(z))$ when $z$ is complex

Tags: logarithms, approximation, approximation-theory

There exist beautiful numerical approximation for calculation of the function
  $$f(z) = \log(1+\exp(z)).$$
In case if $z$ is real, the following can be used
  $$f(z) = \begin{cases} z & z \gg 1 \\ e^{z} & z \ll 1 \\\log(1 + e^z) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

But what about the case when $z$ is complex? What should be the conditions for using the same kind of approximation?

Comment: I think it holds when you condition on the modulus of $z$, but you have to take care of the branch of $\log$ you use.